# How can I enable custom logging on Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apache-2.4

I can't get Apache to produce any access.log output other than what it comes with as default.

I've tried

- changing the logging "nicknames" defined in the global `apache.conf` within the virtual host containers,
- turning logging off completely within the vhost containers
- Writing my own "nicknames" and using them within the vhosts containers

apachectl -M output:

```
log_config_module (static)
```

I know the Ubuntu package maintainers rewrite Apache a lot, I'm wondering if there is some Ubuntu specific switch or change / issue I'm missing that is preventing custom logging?

My desired output is to

1. Simply insert a "test-debug" plain text entry into logs
2. also insert this `\"%{Host}i\"` (domain requested by client)

somthing like:

```
LogFormat "debug-entry %h %l %u %t \"%r\" \"%{Host}i\" %>s %b" myCustom
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log myCustom
```